# SQL query to select range from specific date/time yesterday to specific date/time current day

Tags: sql, sybase, dateadd, getdate, datepart

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
WHERE service_date BETWEEN (dateadd(DD, -1, getdate())) AND (dateadd(DD, 1, getdate())) **---Gives us a last one day data.**
```

but what we really need is data from `07:00 AM` yesterday to `06:59 AM` current day, so I tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
WHERE service_date BETWEEN (dateadd(DD, -1,((DatePart(hh, getdate())) >= 7 ))) **-- Expecting to pull from yesterday 07:00** 
                   AND (dateadd(DD, -1,((DatePart(hh, getdate())) <= 6 ))) **-- to current day till 06:59**
```

but the system didn't like my SQL skills ...PLEASE HELP...!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MS SqlServer?

Comment: Get rid of the `DatePart` functions and change `DATEADD (DD...` to `DATEADD (hh...` subtracting the number of hours instead.

Comment: The solutions I received are great but I forgot to mention that I am querying from a linked Sybase Server, how do I modify one of the given solution to work on Sybase ? Looks like sybase doesn't have datediff.

Comment: According to [this Sybase BOL article](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/X315942.htm) it does have a DATEDIFF.  Perhaps the syntax is simply a bit off.

Comment: I agree and it's definitely something in the code because it says it cannot convert 0 to date.

Comment: It's always good to know error information.  I thought it was strange that DateAdd worked, but DateDiff didn't.  It seems to be the argument and not the function.

Comment: Don't forget, you can accept an answer if you found a solution that worked for you. Read more about accepting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Good thing is all the solutions provided worked well in SQL Server but all of them are getting error "cannot convert 0 to date" when tried in Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

These will get you the dates you are looking for...

```
Select DATEADD(HOUR,-17, (DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))


Select DATEADD(HOUR,7, (DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```

I'm not sure if this is the most effective way but it works.

Comment: --- The solutions I received are great but I forgot to mention that I am querying from a linked Sybase Server, how do I modify one of the given solution to work on Sybase ? Looks like sybase doesn't have datediff.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL Server:

```
Select *
From MyTable
Where MyDateColumn Between DATEADD(hh, 7, Cast(Cast(DATEADD(d, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) As Date) As DateTime)) 
                       And DATEADD(hh, 6, Cast(Cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP As Date) As DateTime))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am querying from a linked Sybase Server.

Comment: @Altimo I won't be much help then.  But you say Sybase has no `DATEDIFF`.  Does it have `DATEADD`?  And a difference between `Date` and `DateTime`?  Otherwise, Henry Liang's solution will probably work, it seems pretty system-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I agree with Andy's solution. Similar approach but his solution is much more elegant and efficient.

Try something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM services 
WHERE service_date
      BETWEEN Convert(DateTime, Convert(nchar(4), DatePart(YYYY, GETDATE())) + '-' 
+ Convert(nchar(2), DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())) + '-' 
+ Convert(nchar(2), DATEPART(DD, Getdate())-1) + ' 7:00:00')
      AND Convert(DateTime, Convert(nchar(4), DatePart(YYYY, GETDATE())) + '-' 
+ Convert(nchar(2), DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())) + '-' 
+ Convert(nchar(2), DATEPART(DD, Getdate())) + ' 6:59:00')
```

The idea is to take the year, month and day from today (or yesterday), and form a new date by concatenate them.

Beware of the culture settings for date format and do some testing before put this code into production.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `mi` (minutes) with `DateAdd`.  Adding 419 minutes to midnight to get `06:59` and a nice round 420 minutes to yesterday midnight for `07:00`

**Edit**: Changed the DateDiff function to work with Sybase.

```
SELECT *
FROM services
WHERE service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, 420, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEDIFF(d, DATE('1900-01-01'), GETDATE()))) 
                       AND DATEADD(mi, 419, DATEADD(d, -0, DATEDIFF(d, DATE('1900-01-01'), GETDATE())));
```

**Edit**: Removing DateDiff function

```
SELECT *
FROM services
WHERE service_date BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, 420, DATEADD(d, - 1, Convert(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)))
                       AND DATEADD(mi, 419, DATEADD(d, - 0, Convert(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111)));
```

Comment: This solution works well in SQL Server, but I forgot to mention that I am querying from a linked Sybase Server, how do I modify this to work on Sybase ? Looks like sybase doesn't have datediff.

Comment: I'm not sure if Sybase `CONVERT` function works the same as SQL Server, but if so the edit removes `DateDiff`.

Comment: I've updated the first example to use the date that SQL Server interprets as zero.

Comment: Sybase (all flavors) supprots both DATEADD()( and DATEDIFF(). In fact, these functions originated in Sybase and ended up in MS SQL Server due to the Sybase heritage. If these functiosn do not seem to work, it may be related to the way the query is pushed down by MSSQL to Sybase.

Comment: @RobV - Good to know.  I thought it would be odd for DATEADD() to be supported, but not DATEDIFF().  It appears that MSSQL has a definition for zero as a valid Date and Sybase does not.